# trying to use "require("zip")" in my lua script,g etting error

Tags: lua, zlib, luajit

I am trying to use `require("zip")`, to open the docx file formate as this comes as zip file. and I am getting these errors :

```
LuaJIT 2.0.5 -- Copyright (C) 2005-2017 Mike Pall. http://luajit.org/

luajit-2.0.5: CVE-2015-1650.lua:24: module 'zip' not found:

    no field package.preload['zip']
    no file './zip.lua'
    no file '/usr/local/share/luajit-2.0.5/zip.lua'
    no file '/usr/local/share/lua/5.1/zip.lua'
    no file '/usr/local/share/lua/5.1/zip/init.lua'
    no file './zip.so'
    no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.1/zip.so'
    no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.1/loadall.so'
    stack traceback:
    [C]: in function 'require'
    CVE-2015-1650.lua:24: in main chunk
    [C]: at 0x558124871440
```

I can understand there are some packages which are missing, but which package.

NOTE: I have installed almost all the lua-zip, zlib, libzip package available.

Help Me!!! I am stuck here.

Comment: which library are you trying to use? the way you're loading a package does not match the packages you have installed or the locatation where you have installed them

Comment: *how* and *where* did you install the packages though?

Comment: for all the packages i have used either "sudo apt install <package>" or " tar ball".

Comment: I am practicing Lua for Suricata, one CVE-2015-1650 etpro has given the lua file, i am trying to run that for now.
https://github.com/EmergingThreats/et-luajit-scripts/blob/master/CVE-2015-1650.lua

Comment: am still looking for some advise or help...